# Automatic numbering proof lines in lplfitch

Tags: line-numbering, lplfitch, automatic

I often use lplfitch package to write proofs. Is there a way to automatically number the demonstration lines? At the moment, I enter the numbering manually with the parameter \pline[NUMBERING]{....}

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\renewcommand*{\formula}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}

\begin{document}
\fitchprf{\pline[1.]{P \rightarrow Q}\\\pline[2.]{P}}
{\pline[3.]{Q}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Hi Simone, yours is a good solution as long as you don't use subproof. Unfortunately, by using subproof at some point the numbering starts from 1 again. See this:

```
\fitchprf{\pline{P \lif Q}} {\subproof{\pline{P}} {\pline{Q}\\\pline{Q \lor R}}\pline{P \lif (Q \lor R)} }
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Without the optional parameter of `\pline` will add a sequential  number.

[image: d]

Example from the manual page #9: `subproof` 3-level deep.

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\renewcommand*{\formula}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}

%******************************* added <<<<<<<<<<
\newcounter{countline}
\newcounter{oldcountline}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\pline{\@ifnextchar[\@plinenum{\@plinenum[\stepcounter{countline}\thecountline.]}}% format the line numbers
\xapptocmd{\fitchprf}{\setcounter{oldcountline}{\thecountline}\setcounter{countline}{0}}{}{}% reset the counter for a new proof     
\renewcommand{\subproof}[2]{&\fitchprf{#1}{#2}\\\setcounter{countline}{\theoldcountline}}   % continue the sequence if subproof
\makeatother
%*******************************

\begin{document}
    
manual numbering 
    
\fitchprf{\pline[1.]{P \rightarrow Q}\\\pline[2.]{P}}
{\pline[3.]{Q}} 
    
\bigskip

with auto numbering 

\fitchprf{\pline{P \rightarrow Q}\\
\pline{P}}
{\pline{Q}}

\bigskip

a new proof 

\fitchprf{\pline{R \rightarrow S}\\
\pline{R}}
{\pline{T}}

\bigskip
    
subproof with   auto  numbering         

\fitchprf{\pline{P \lif Q}} {
    \subproof{\pline{P}}
     {\pline{Q}\\
     \pline{Q \lor R}}
    \pline{P \lif (Q \lor R)} 
    }


\newpage        
    
subproof with   manual numbering    

\fitchprf{}{
    \subproof{\pline[1.]{\uni{x}{(Cube(x)\lif Small(x))}}}{
        \subproof{\pline[2.]{\exi{x}{Cube(x)}}}{
            \subproof{\pline[3.]{Cube(a)}}{
                \pline[4.]{Cube(a)\lif Small(a)}\\
                \pline[5.]{Small(a)}\\
                \pline[6.]{\exi{x}{Small(x)}}
            }
            \pline[7.]{\exi{x}{Small(x)}}
        }
        \pline[8.]{\exi{x}{Cube(x)}\lif \exi{x}{Small(x)}}
    }
    \pline[9.]{\brokenform{(\uni{x}{(Cube(x)\lif Small(x))}\lif}{
            \formula{(\exi{x}{Cube(x)} \lif \exi{x}{Small(x)})}}}
}

\bigskip

subproof with   auto  numbering     

\fitchprf{}{
    \subproof{\pline{\uni{x}{(Cube(x)\lif Small(x))}}}{
        \subproof{\pline{\exi{x}{Cube(x)}}}{
            \subproof{\pline{Cube(a)}}{
                \pline{Cube(a)\lif Small(a)}\\
                \pline{Small(a)}\\
                \pline{\exi{x}{Small(x)}}
            }
            \pline{\exi{x}{Small(x)}}
        }
        \pline{\exi{x}{Cube(x)}\lif \exi{x}{Small(x)}}
    }
    \pline{\brokenform{(\uni{x}{(Cube(x)\lif Small(x))}\lif}{
            \formula{(\exi{x}{Cube(x)} \lif \exi{x}{Small(x)})}}}
}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Simon Dispa, yours is a good solution as long as you don't use subproof. Unfortunately, by using subproof at some point the numbering starts from 1 again. Try this code to see the effect: \fitchprf{\pline{P \lif Q}}
{\subproof{\pline{P}}
{\pline{Q}\\\pline{Q \lor R}}\pline{P \lif (Q \lor R)} }

Comment: @Frank Please see the updated answer.

Comment: you are a genius!